# How do I select and copy text in Emacs using the keyboard?

Tags: clipboard, emacs

How do I select text using the keyboard?

After selecting text, I click on **Edit**. It shows `Copy <copy>`.

How do I copy text using the keyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try turning on [PC Selection mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PcSelectionMode). See also [the copy/paste page on emacswiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CopyAndPaste)

Comment: Is PcSelectionMode also support for normal emacs or should I install another emacs? By the way,I know C- means ctrl, M- means alt, and what's S- ?

Comment: It should be available in the default installation of GNU Emacs. You can try turning it on with `M-x pc-selection-mode`

Comment: Thank you~ I have loaded pc-selection-mode. How to press S- ?

Comment: @sam: I suppose `S` is the `Shift` modifier

Answer (score 37):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd> to mark start of block.

Move cursor until end of block.

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd> to copy

Move to insert position

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>y</kbd> to paste

Comment: I can't select by ctrl+space,and if I use mouse to select,I also can't copy by alt+w. What happened?

Comment: @sam: Ctrl-space do not select, only mark the start of block. Then you will see the selection expanding if you move the cursor.

Comment: Sorry for my typo unclearly,I know I should use keyboard to move cursor. When I press Ctrl+space it just open input method like scim. Even when I use mouse to select,I also can't copy by alt+w. Because when I open gedit to paste,it appears nothing.

Comment: I mean to copy and paste inside emacs itself, don't know if it work to paste outside of it. And you can try Ctrl-@ instead of Ctrl-space.

Comment: I have tried ctrl+2 and ctrl+shift+2 (means ctrl+@) with keyboard's direction key(up,down,left,right on the right of keyboard), but I also can't select any characters.

Comment: Works perfectly in Emacs in Android Termux

Comment: If you want to cut instead of copy, you can press `Ctrl` instead of `Alt`.

Answer (score 4):

I found another way just the same as windows' operations.

*Emacs menu* > *Options* > *C-x/C-c/C-v Cut and Paste (CUA)*.

That option will let me use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow keys</kbd> to select, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy, and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste.

But it only work in emacs. It could not paste on gedit.

If I want to paste to gedit, I should use *menu* > *edit* > *copy*.

I didn't find any shortcut to *menu* > *edit* > *copy*.